# Where to ask theoretical AI (neural network questions)

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a theoretical question about artificial intelligence (in particular neural networks). It clearly does not belong to stackoverflow, but the problem is that we do not have a dedicated AI site and I am confused which one of these sites (all have neural network/AI questions and tags) might be a better place:

- [data science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)
- [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)
- [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/)
- [cs theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

By a better place I mean that I will be able to find experts knowledgable in this area.

**P.S.** [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278354/1090562) (but the question is related to implementation, whereas mine is theoretical) was asked 8 month ago, but with no response.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57719/artificial-intelligence looks like there was going to be an AI site, but it was closed down due to lack of activity. That does not bode well for your chances of netting answers to questions regardless of where you post them.

Comment: Having said that, programmers does have an artificial-intelligence topic: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence  - that is of course programming oriented, but who better grasps the theory than the person who is putting it into practice?

Comment: @Gimby Not AI specifically, but I've come across plenty of programmers who definitely don't grasp the theory, despite being the ones (trying) to put it into practice.

Comment: @Gimby sorry to tell you, but there is a huge amount of people who do not know anything except of "if I paste these 20 lines and press enter the magic will happen"

Comment: [cs.se], or [cstheory.se] if it's cutting-edge.

Comment: @SalvadorDali (and anthony) that is context-sensitive; AI is a whole other ballgame that people who only copy and paste have no possibility of getting anywhere.

Comment: cf computer science [artificial-intelligence](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) and also [machine-learning](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) tags & further discussion in [cs chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23438552#23438552)

Comment: You should ask where asking about ANN is not on-topic :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try asking at [Artificial Intelligence SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence/visit), it started private beta last week.

[image]

Currently it has variety of questions and the goal is *bring people from this one particular field, which exists in between all above in one place*.

Answer (score 23):

AI is a branch of computer science. [The typical scope size for a Stack Exchange site is that of a university department](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/09/merging-season/). So [look for a site](https://stackexchange.com/sites) about computer science.

[image: Computer Science]

Computer Science welcomes questions about all fields of theoretical and applied computer science at all levels.

There is also a site for research-level questions in theoretical computer science where some AI questions may fit: [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai.artificial-intel).

Some questions about machine learning may find a more specialized audience on [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @SalvadorDali Somewhat true, but the learning curve is *far* less. Programming is programming, unless the whole darn post is in Portuguese (or some other language).

Answer (score 9):

**If the question is research level**, [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) seems like the best bet.

They have a tag for it: [ai.artificial-intel](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai.artificial-intel)

Answer (score 9):

*Artificial Intelligence*, *Data Mining*, *Machine Learning* or whatever you would like to call it has many facets. On **stackoverflow** it seems that only a very small amount of those questions get good answers. Often that's because of bad questions that should have been closed in the first place, but also because for most questions not a programmer is needed, but someone familiar with algorithmic theory and/or a lot of math and statistics.

Machine learning is a very broad field. Some techniques require a (deep?) understanding in bayesian statistics. As many of us computer scientists and programmers are not familiar with bayesian statistics, such questions should probably find their home at **stats**.

Other techniques are based not so much on mathematical theory, but on very clever algorithms. I agree with commenters that **ComputerScience** or **Theoretical Computer Science** could be a good match.

I guess *Artificial Neural Networks* belong to the second group. Many computer scientists are familiar with the technique and algorithms and apply it in their daily work and research. I guess there's a good chance to get an answer at either of the two computer science sites.

Answer (score 7):

For machine learning and neural networks, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning+or+neural-networks) is by far your best bet.  They have 10x the traffic for the tags [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) and [neural-networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neural-networks) than the next highest site, [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning+or+neural-networks).  For AI questions outside of machine learning or neural networks (e.g., heuristic search, theorem proving, genetic programming etc.) the [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com) or [Theoretical CS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I wish it was in scope here. In the typical engineer/scientist distinction, scientists have a lot to do with bridges but the only one *building* them are engineers.

As someone who's just working with AI, I'm really looking forward to AI dropping out of the realm of academia (computer science) and into engineering (developers).

As a computer scientist myself who works in development, the development community is *much* more friendly and helpful with complex topics. There's a point of pride in development towards taking ethereal issues and making them digestible. If ever there was a place that's needed, it's AI.